# How to return a value from a function in an efficient way? (c++)

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization

I am not a professional CS programmer.

I wrote a function to calculate displacement between two images.
The function looks like this.

```
void myFunction(Mat img1, Mat img2)
{
    do some calculation;
}
```

And in the main function, i use "QueryPerformanceFrequency" to get the time cost of my function.
Part of the main function looks like this.

```
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&nFreq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&nBeginTime);

for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
{
     myFunction(prevImg, nextImg);
}

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&nFreq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&nEndTime);
```

In this way i can get the average time cost of my function is about 10 us, which is pretty fast.

But the problem is, I need my funtion return a value.
So i edit my function into this:

```
double myFunction(Mat img1, Mat img2)
{
    do some calculation;
    double displacement = result;

    return displacement;
}
```

The main function is:

```
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&nFreq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&nBeginTime);

for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
{
     double displacement = myFunction(prevImg, nextImg);
}

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&nFreq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&nEndTime);
```

When i run this test, the average time cost is about 500us, which is very slow.

The only difference is that I return a value from my function in the later situation,
and i suppose this cause the program become slow.

Is there any faster way to return value from a function?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this the real code (i.e. `displacement` is not used)? Are you compiling your code with optimizations on? Compiler should notice that return value is unused and produce exactly same code in both cases.

Comment: I don't think this is only because of returning a value. You also might have an additional cast to `double` you didn't have before which costs time. We can't say without knowing what is actually done in this function. You could compare a total empty function with one returning a constant value without any operation - dont think there will be such a big difference

Comment: Also, with full optimization and your original (void) function not actually returning any result, the compiler may (legally) disregard much of the code/calculation in that function if the result is never used.